# Angularjs: function not return bolean value even though webApi gives response as true

Tags: angularjs

This My Mark-up code

```
<button id="btnUploadFiles" class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-4  btn primaryButton" data-ng-click="uploadFilesToPdm()">
                    <span class=" btn-circle"></span>
                    Upload
                </button>
```

My controller code

```
$scope.uploadFilesToPdm = function () {
            if (validateLoad()){do something further...}
        }

function validateLoad() {
            selectedItems = {
                EnvironmentId: 52,
                ApplicationId: 23,
                UserId: ""
            }
            var data = fileUploadService.validateLoad.save({}, selectedItems);
            data.$promise.then(function (response) {
                if (!response.isValid) {
                    alert(warning.messageMandatoryFileLoad + response.requiredFileType);
                }
                return response.isValid;
            }, function (error) {
            });
        }
```

My WebApi method returning true and is working fine.
and response is also gets caught in ValidateLoad() method.

However in uploadFilesToPdm if condition is not able to evaluate and function wont proceed to "do further something...". Please suggest, if am missing something.

Comment: the data.$promise.then(function... is being done async. You lose scope of validateLoad() in the callback, thus the method is returning nothing

Comment: is there any other way to execute "do something further" part after getting return value from validateLoad()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it by returning the promise:

```
$scope.uploadFilesToPdm = function() {
  validateLoad().then(function(response) {
    if (!response.isValid) {
      return alert(warning.messageMandatoryFileLoad + response.requiredFileType);
    }
    //do something further..
  }, function(error) {});
}

function validateLoad() {
  selectedItems = {
    EnvironmentId: 52,
    ApplicationId: 23,
    UserId: ""
  }
  return fileUploadService.validateLoad.save({}, selectedItems).$promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `validateLoad()` function doesn't return anything, which means it effectively returns underfined, which is falsy.

You need to return a boolean from that function. But that's impossible, because you'll only know the boolean value long after the function has returned. The boolean will only be known once the file upload has complete. So what you can return is a promise of boolean. But then you can't check if the promise is true or false. You can only check if it's resolved as true or as false:

```
$scope.uploadFilesToPdm = function () {
    validateLoad().then(function(valid) {
        if (valid) {do something further...}
    });
};


function validateLoad() {
    selectedItems = {
        EnvironmentId: 52,
        ApplicationId: 23,
        UserId: ""
    }

    var data = fileUploadService.validateLoad.save({}, selectedItems);
    return data.$promise.then(function (response) {
        if (!response.isValid) {
            alert(warning.messageMandatoryFileLoad + response.requiredFileType);
        }
        return response.isValid;
    });
}
```

Read [the blog post](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/) I wrote about promises and how to avoid its traps.

Answer (score 0):

As Lucas said in his comment: You need to "wait" for the async call to finish. The easiest way to achieve that in your case is to return the promise from the `validateLoad()` function like TJ's answer is showing it.

There's another way of doing it by using $q which is an antipattern but sometimes used for code separation.

```
function validateLoad() {
  q = $q.defered();

        selectedItems = {
            EnvironmentId: 52,
            ApplicationId: 23,
            UserId: ""
        }
        var data = fileUploadService.validateLoad.save({}, selectedItems);
        return data.$promise.then(function (response) {
            if (!response.isValid) {
                alert(warning.messageMandatoryFileLoad + response.requiredFileType);
                q.reject(false);
            }
            q.resolve(response.isValid);
        });

   return q.promise;
}
```

In this case you create another promise that you return and then use in your `$scope.uploadFilesToPdm` function.